# GoDaddy custom domain hosted with Heroku throwing privacy error

Tags: django, heroku, https, ssl-certificate, hosting

I'm having trouble getting the custom domain I bought from GoDaddy to work with the Django app I have hosted on Heroku's free dyno. The Heroku app is accessible from the custom domain, however, I keep getting a privacy error from chrome. See below:

[image: chrome privacy warning]

My Heroku dashboard confirms that I have added my custom domain. I have tried doing this through both the CLI and GUI, with no different results.

[image: Heroku dashboard domain config]

My DNS settings on my domain in GoDaddy are configured as follows. Someone had mentioned the CNAME setting should be the .herokudns domain generated by the addition of the custom domain in the Heroku dashboard, but when I make that change the website is not accessible at all. The Heroku app is named: 
desolate-basin-60228 and can be accessible at https://desolate-basin-60228.herokuapp.com/

[image: GoDaddy DNS settings]

and in GoDaddy I have confirmed that my forwarding is set to http (not https as I don't need a security cert. for this site):

[image: GoDaddy forwarding]

I also thought that it may be an issue with my Django settings.py file. So I adjusted any line with mention of https. This did not have any effect.

[image: Django settings]

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this Heroku help center resource](https://help.heroku.com/NH44MODG/my-root-domain-isn-t-working-what-s-wrong), if your site needs SSL support, then it's not possible to set up a GoDaddy domain with Heroku. That could explain why you're having trouble.

However, there may be a few workarounds:

- https://domainpromo.com/1831/godaddy-heroku-setup
- https://medium.com/@successengineer/how-to-setup-heroku-with-godaddy-d8e936d10849